# In statistics, what is the meaning of $Z_{0.3}$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

What is the meaning of $Z_{0.3}$ and how do I calculate it?

I know it was calculated this way:
$$Z_{0.3} = -Z_{0.7} = -0.52$$

I tried to follow the *General Distribution* table but I can't seem to find the way to get this.

It's quite hard to look for information about a term you have no clue how it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the quantile of the standard normal distribution. In other words, if $\Phi(x)$ is the cdf of a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1, then $Z_{0.3}$ simply means the value of $x$ for which $\Phi(x)=0.3$. Essentially, it's the inverse of the cdf.

The equation given follows from the symmetry of the standard normal curve about the mean 0.

If you have access to a table a table of values of the cdf $\Phi$ then you can look for the value closest to 0.7 in the table and see which $x$ gives that $Z$ value.

Hope this helps.